# Rails - Parent/child relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, parent-child

I'm currently using a standard one-to-one relationship to handle parent/child relationships:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :category
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Is there a recommended way to do it or is this ok?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You will need to tweak the names you are using to get this working - you specify the name of the relationship, and then tell AR what the class is:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :child, :class_name => "Category"
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category" 
end
```

Comment: How do we find the child categories for the specific parents.

Comment: You can just use parent.child?

Comment: What should be written in the routes if want something like Category/parent/3/child/1

Answer (score 14):

I found that I had to make a minor change to @equivalent8's solution to make it work for Rails 5 (5.1.4):

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Category", foreign_key: 'parent_id'
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category", foreign_key: 'parent_id', :optional => true
end
```

Without the `foreign_key` declaration, Rails tries to find the children by organization_id instead of parent_id and chokes.

Rails also chokes without the `:optional => true` declaration on the belongs_to association since belongs_to requires an instance to be assigned by default in Rails 5.  In this case, you would have to assign an infinite number of parents.

Comment: Very detailed! I will apply this.

Answer (score 6):

has_many version:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Category"
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Category" 
end

#migratio
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration 
 def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.integer :parent_id
      t.string  :title

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
 end
end

# RSpec test 
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Category do
  describe '#parent & #children' do
    it 'should be able to do parent tree' do
      c1 = Category.new.save!
      c2 = Category.new(parent: c1).save!

      expect(c1.children).to include(c2)
      expect(c2.parent).to eq c1
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Using Rails 5.1.4.  I found that when I follow the above c2.parent gives me c1, but c1.children gives me an error:  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'categories.category_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`category_id` = 5

Comment: try `has_many :children, :class_name => "Category", foreign_key: "id"`

Comment: @equivalent8 this is incorrect, only foreign_key: 'parent_id' and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think , should be foreign_key

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :children, :foreign_key => "parent_id" , :class_name => "Product"
 belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Product" 
end
```

Console :

```
2.4.3 :004 > product  = Product.find_by_name "BOB"

 => #<Product id: 1, name: "BOB", parent_id: nil>
2.4.3 :005 > product.children
D, [2019-11-07T14:56:14.273606 #66632] DEBUG -- :   

Product Load (0.7ms) SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."parent_id" = $1  [["parent_id", 1]]

 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy 
[#<Product id: 7, parent_id: 1>, 
#<Product id: 8,  parent_id: 1>, 
#<Product id: 9, parent_id: 1>]>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a *model* `Category` and a *table* `categories` (in schema.rb)  you could do this to the model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :children, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: :parent_id
    belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category', optional: true
end
```

and this as a migration:

```
class AddParentIdToCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :categories, :parent_id, :integer
  end
end
```

NOTE: In newer versions of Ruby you don't need the rocket hashes `=>`

Answer (score -5):

Since the relation is symmetric, I actually find that different than what Toby wrote, that I prefer the following:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :parent, :class_name => "Category" 
  belongs_to :children, :class_name => "Category"
end
```

For some reason "has one parent, many children" is the way my mind things, not "has many parents, only one child"

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me.  Why would an object belong to its children?  Plus, the author stated that the relationship was one-to-one, so I don't understand why you're pluralizing it.

Comment: this should be exactly other way around, look answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/38791328/473040