# rails active model query parent child from same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having following database scheme

```
id    parent     child
1      0          No parent1
2      0          No parent2
3      1          Has parent 1
4      1          Has parent 1
5      2          Has parent 2
```

Consider the above table as my table schema, Now how can I query it or use it to display something like this

```
No parent1
    * Has parent 1
    * Has parent 1
No parent2
    * Has parent 2
```

Here is my controller at present

```
@locations = Location.all.order(parent: :asc)
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion how can I do this

Answer (score 2):

I resolved as describe bellow:

model/location.rb

```
  has_many :childrens, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: :parent
  belongs_to :parent,  class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: :id

  def self.order_by_parent(top: nil)
    locations = Location.where(parent: top)

    locations_return = []
    locations.each do |location|
      locations_return << location
      auxs = Location.order_by_parent(top: location.id)
      auxs.each do |aux|
        locations_return << aux
      end
    end
    locations_return
  end
```

locations_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @locations = Location.order_by_parent(top: nil)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [group_by](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by). Also, here's a link to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481047/group-activerecord-relation/21481642#21481642).

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing parent child relationship. Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917559/rails-parent-child-relationships).

Model should be something like this

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :childrens, :class_name => "Location"
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Location" 
end
```

Add `parent_id` and `child_id` field in your location table.

Then call `@locations = Location.parents`

```
@locations.each{|location|
 location.name
 Childrens:
 location.childrens.each{|child|
  child.name
 }
}
```

Comment: The plural of _child_ is _children_